# threejs fbx convertor (R58) cannot work with JSONLoader

Tags: three.js, fbx

I'm using threejs(R58). I convert the FBX model to threejs json file via utils/convertors/fbx/convert_to_threejs.py. When I use THREE.JSONLoader to load the json file, brower throw exception in the line "for ( i = 0; i < json.uvs.length; i++ )".
I find the format of the generated json file is not matched with the JSONLoader.
Which FBX convertor should I use? Why R58 has this inconsistent convertor tool?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's my mistake. The generated js file via utils/convertors/fbx/convert_to_threejs.py is a scene type js file. I should use SceneLoader instead of JSONLoader.